# Internet Explorer, Flash, WordPress conflict?

Tags: flash, wordpress, explorer

I am currently building a portfolio site here... http://2x2design.co.uk/

It has a subtle flash header animation which seems to be working fine in all but Explorer where it causes all sorts of problems, particularly when you are scrolling across the page.

I need to identify what part of the code on that page is causing the problem. I know it is not the swf as I have tried substituting that with other swf's from sites which work fine in IE and the same problem occurs. The site is running from wordpress, it has a few plugins enabled and the doctype is XHTML+RDFa 1.0 for use with facebook social plugins.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you remove the SWF from the header, does the problem disappear? I ask because I've never seen such a thing caused by a simple Flash animation, but my experience with Flash is not related to web design.

Comment: If you remove the SWF the problem is gone yes. The problem seems to be that when scrolling in IE over the flash content it jitters and the scrolling is slowed. I tried putting the embed code on a simple page with nothing but it on it and it scrolls in IE completely fine. That's what gave me the idea something else on the page is conflicting with it and causing IE to play up.

Comment: Is the problem only with the older versions of IE? If so, I would suggest replacing the animation with static image only for older browser. Someone with an old browser has probably a slower machine anyway and the animation is purely aesthetic.

Comment: I might end up doing that Alexcp but I still worry why on this version of IE it's stressing in is perfectly fine with some other flash based websites.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of the transparent background. But like I said, I think the best thing would be to replace it with an image on older browser.